# Executing Multiple Queries in Single class in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I am facing a problem when i am going to execute 2 queries in a class
only first one query is executing,help me to solve the problem 
I tried some coding below

```
public class DamageCopyingData extends HttpServlet {

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String damageIssuePeriod = request.getParameter("DamageIssuePeriod");
    String damageTrNo = request.getParameter("DamageTrNo");
    int Dno = Integer.parseInt(damageTrNo);
    String returnNo = request.getParameter("ReturnNo");
    int Rno = Integer.parseInt(returnNo);
    String returnDate = request.getParameter("ReturnDate");
    String returnRef = request.getParameter("ReturnRef");

    String voucherNo = request.getParameter("VoucherNo");
    int vno = Integer.parseInt(voucherNo);
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306", "root", "dinga");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO project.damagereturn(TransactionType,VoucherNo,VoucherDate,VoucherRef,Salesman,SalesRoute,Location,IssuetoCostCentre,Description,PrintCost,ProductNo,PackSize,CostPrice,DamageType,QtyPack,QtyPcs,Weight,ToWeight,TotalAmount,Total,ProductName,BatchNo,ExpiryDate,UOM,OnHandPacks,OnHandPieces) SELECT * FROM project.damagevoucher WHERE VoucherNo =?");

        ps.setInt(1, vno);
        int rs = ps.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("value rs"+rs);
        System.out.println("success...1");

        if (rs==1) {

            PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement("Update project.damagereturn(DamageIssuePeriod,DamageTrNo,ReturnNo,ReturnDate,ReturnRef) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps1.setString(1, damageIssuePeriod);
            ps1.setInt(2, Dno);
            ps1.setInt(3, Rno);
            ps1.setString(4, returnDate);
            ps1.setString(5, returnRef);

            int rs1 = ps1.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("value rs1"+rs1);
            System.out.println("success...2");
        }
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

1. 1st query will copy data from project.damagevoucher table and paste in new table project.damagereturn
2. 2nd will update the table adding some details but that query is not executing please help me to solve the problem

Comment: Do you need to commit after the Insert and Update?

Comment: not needed i think ,if we did no problem

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc In the given code, the connection is in auto commit mode.

Comment: What is the value of `rs` after executing the insert? Is it possible that more than one row was inserted?

Comment: 1.It is not Printing anything for rs value ..